# How to add class Angular 2

Tags: class, angular, binding

I'm trying to override only a part of my default class (glyphicon-eye-...).

With this code :

```
<i [class.glyphicon-eye-open] = "isOpen" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></i>
```

I get `class = "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close glyphicon-eye-open"`

How can i get this instead  `class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ng-class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) instead

```
<i [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-eye-close': !isOpen, 'glyphicon-eye-open': isOpen}" class="glyphicon"></i>
```